# How do I return conditional formatting properties without adding additional rules in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

If a cell has conditional formatting that uses an Icon Set (my current situation is using the Traffic Light Icon Set), is there a way to identify in VBA what particular icon is showing in that cell?

The motivation behind it is that it will correspond to a red/amber/green value which I'm exporting in a SQL statement, so I need to find it in VBA.

I can add new rules and select icon sets just fine:

```
Set Newiconset = Range("H3").FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition
```

It's returning the properties of an existing set of rules that has me hung up.

Thanks for your help - I scoured StackOverflow for a solution and couldn't find it.  If someone's solved this, let me know and I'll gladly remove my question.

Answer (score 0):

Bad news:  what I'm looking to do technically isn't possible.

Here's why:

Excel data is stored in XML files in a main Zip file (you can experiment with this by renaming an xlsx file to zip and opening it).  Inside the data is stored in XML files, and when you finally find your workbook, you can see that the data is stored as the actual conditions themselves, with the range values and such.    Excel then takes those and computes the result on the fly every time you look at that file.  States are not saved when saving the file unfortunately.  It's worth noting though that the current state of formulas is stored - I'm assuming this is how accessing values from external workbooks is handled.

This explains why you can set and read the rules just fine, but since there's nothing officially to read a value from you can't "get" the data.